# Why using search Title:html5 not return anything while title:html5 works

Tags: support, status-completed, search

Why using search `Title:html5` not return anything while `title:html5` works. Using `Title:` for other keywords works fine.

Comment: Seems to affect all keywords ending in a number, and doesn't seem to be activating the search option.

Answer (score 2):

I added a few cases in the new search parser to handle this, advanced options are all now case-insensitive (rather than the native lucene field handling that was used before).

Comment: Sometimes I use a device which capitalizes first letter and I have to do more work to lower case it. A good UI should not force users to enter text in a certain case if the system is case insensitive. SO should take the input and lower case it in this case. Eg: url's are not case sensitive. StackOverfloW.cOm works.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich - I'm not *completely* following here: "if the system is case insensitive"...but it *is* case-sensitive, that's your bug report is it not? This is something I will look at when we're making larger changes to search parsing, but not something immediate.  Parsing the search is actually a quite complicated process, something we're looking at simplifying, now that it's evolved into something more stable in terms of a feature-set.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bug. I would say SO is not proactive enough and it's not helping the user. How about being like Google? Google doesn't stop working if I misspelled a keyword. It says "Did you mean.. " and brings back results for the correct spelling. In this case I am happy and thankful. SO can be smarter and say "Did you mean title:.." and brings back results. Or lowercase Title if the search parser understands "title" only. Being more proactive goes along way instead of bringing nothing back and blame the user.

Comment: @Tony: Google also has several orders of magnitude more engineers than SO has!